# Flux: filtering exceptions

Tags: java, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I'm trying to filter exceptions from Flux/ Mono with `onErrorContinue`, but it never gets triggered.

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;
import reactor.test.StepVerifier;


class FluxOnErrorContinueTest {

    @Test
    public void fluxTest() {
        Flux<String> fluxOne = Flux.just("one")
                .onErrorContinue(IllegalArgumentException.class, (ex, value) -> System.out.println("fluxOne: " + ex.getMessage()));
        Flux<String> fluxTwo = Flux.<String>error(() -> new IllegalArgumentException("error"))
                .onErrorContinue(IllegalArgumentException.class, (ex, value) -> System.out.println("fluxTwo: " +ex.getMessage()));
        Flux<String> fluxThree = Flux.just("three", "four", "five")
                .onErrorContinue(IllegalArgumentException.class, (ex, value) -> System.out.println("fluxThree: " +ex.getMessage()));

        Flux<String> sourceFlux = fluxOne.concatWith(fluxTwo).concatWith(fluxThree);

        Flux<String> filteredFlux = sourceFlux
                .onErrorContinue(IllegalArgumentException.class, (ex, value) -> System.out.println("filteredFlux: " + ex.getMessage()));

        StepVerifier.create(filteredFlux)
                .expectNextCount(4)
                .verifyComplete();

    }
}
```

I would expect to get the four string and a log on the console with the exception message, but I get:

```
12:15:15.191 [main] DEBUG reactor.util.Loggers$LoggerFactory - Using Slf4j logging framework

java.lang.AssertionError: expectation "expectNextCount(4)" failed (expected: count = 4; actual: counted = 1; signal: onError(java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: error))

    at reactor.test.ErrorFormatter.assertionError(ErrorFormatter.java:105)
    at reactor.test.ErrorFormatter.failPrefix(ErrorFormatter.java:94)
    at reactor.test.ErrorFormatter.fail(ErrorFormatter.java:64)
    at reactor.test.ErrorFormatter.failOptional(ErrorFormatter.java:79)
    at reactor.test.DefaultStepVerifierBuilder$DefaultVerifySubscriber.checkCountMismatch(DefaultStepVerifierBuilder.java:1258)
    at reactor.test.DefaultStepVerifierBuilder$DefaultVerifySubscriber.onSignalCount(DefaultStepVerifierBuilder.java:1489)
    at reactor.test.DefaultStepVerifierBuilder$DefaultVerifySubscriber.onExpectation(DefaultStepVerifierBuilder.java:1341)
    at reactor.test.DefaultStepVerifierBuilder$DefaultVerifySubscriber.onError(DefaultStepVerifierBuilder.java:1030)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextStart$ContextStartSubscriber.onError(FluxContextStart.java:117)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.onError(Operators.java:1748)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators.error(Operators.java:181)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxErrorSupplied.subscribe(FluxErrorSupplied.java:61)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Flux.subscribe(Flux.java:7921)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatArray$ConcatArraySubscriber.onComplete(FluxConcatArray.java:207)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatArray.subscribe(FluxConcatArray.java:80)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextStart.subscribe(FluxContextStart.java:49)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Flux.subscribe(Flux.java:7921)
    at reactor.test.DefaultStepVerifierBuilder$DefaultStepVerifier.verify(DefaultStepVerifierBuilder.java:801)
    at reactor.test.DefaultStepVerifierBuilder$DefaultStepVerifier.verify(DefaultStepVerifierBuilder.java:772)
    at reactor.test.DefaultStepVerifierBuilder.verifyComplete(DefaultStepVerifierBuilder.java:644)
    at com.myorg.FluxOnErrorContinueTest.fluxTest(FluxOnErrorContinueTest.java:21)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:532)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$6(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:171)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:72)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:167)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:114)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:59)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$4(NodeTestTask.java:108)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:72)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:98)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:74)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1540)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$4(NodeTestTask.java:112)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:72)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:98)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:74)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1540)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$4(NodeTestTask.java:112)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:72)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:98)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:74)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:220)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$6(DefaultLauncher.java:188)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:202)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:181)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:128)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:74)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
    Suppressed: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: error
        at com.myorg.FluxOnErrorContinueTest.lambda$fluxTest$0(FluxOnErrorContinueTest.java:14)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxErrorSupplied.subscribe(FluxErrorSupplied.java:60)
        ... 48 more
```

How can I filter exceptions (try-catch equivalent)?

I also tried with Mono and responses from WebClient.

In the Javadoc "Error Mode Support javadoc section" gets mentioned, but I couldn't find that section. Do you have any links?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that `onErrorContinue` in the test is applied to whole `sourceFlux`. Probably, what you need - is recover from failure for each `Publisher` that is `concatWith` using [`onErrorResume`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#onErrorResume-java.lang.Class-java.util.function.Function-) operator:

```
    @Test
    public void fluxTest() {
        Function<Throwable, Publisher<String>> fallback = error -> {
            if (error instanceof IllegalArgumentException) {
                System.out.println(error.getMessage());
                return Flux.empty();
            } else {
                return Flux.error(error);
            }
        };

        Flux<String> sourceFlux = Flux.just("one")
                .concatWith(Flux.<String>error(() -> new IllegalArgumentException("error"))
                        .onErrorResume(fallback))
                .concatWith(Flux.just("three", "four", "five")
                        .onErrorResume(fallback));

        StepVerifier.create(sourceFlux)
                .expectNextCount(4)
                .verifyComplete();
    }
```

Or, if you need to handle only `IllegalArgumentException`:

```
    @Test
    public void fluxTest() {
        Function<Throwable, Publisher<String>> fallback = error -> {
            System.out.println(error.getMessage());
            return Flux.empty();
        };

        Flux<String> sourceFlux = Flux.just("one")
                .concatWith(Flux.<String>error(() -> new IllegalArgumentException("error"))
                        .onErrorResume(IllegalArgumentException.class, fallback))
                .concatWith(Flux.just("three", "four", "five")
                        .onErrorResume(IllegalArgumentException.class, fallback));

        StepVerifier.create(sourceFlux)
                .expectNextCount(4)
                .verifyComplete();
    }
```

Comment: I tried it both ways, but `onErrorContinue` does not get triggered.
Hmm, you're using `onErrorResume` instead.

Comment: Yes, [`onErrorContinue`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#onErrorContinue-java.util.function.BiConsumer-) doesn't seem suitable for the task.

Comment: So, for which cases `onErrorContinue` can be used then? It doesn't even seem to get triggered (no output). From Javadoc: "Let compatible operators upstream recover from errors by dropping the incriminating element from the sequence and continuing with subsequent elements."

Comment: `onErrorContinue` is not supported by all operators (I believe it's mentioned in javadoc).

Comment: Typically, to emulate different semantics of `try-catch`/`try-catch-finally` you can use different operators, like `onErrorReturn`,`onErrorMap`, `onErrorResume`.

Comment: yes, I read that, but I couldn't find the section "Error Mode Support javadoc section". It seems the standard Flux implementations such as return by WebClient or Flux.error don't support onErrorContinue? Strange...

Comment: btw, [official reference](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#error.handling) doesn't even mention `onErrorContinue`. So, I would suggest to use it judiciously and not rely on it too much.